# Access order history with the payment method not used anymore?

Tags: orders, payment, magento1.9.2.4

I used to have one Stripe extension and have some order histories with it.

Now I use different extension for Stripe payment, so I don't need the previous one. And I also do not want to keep as it is not compatible with the Magento 1.9.2.4 .

However, if I uninstall the old extension , sure I cannot access order history.

Is there any way to see an order history without the old extension installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update your db and replace the value in table `sales_flat_order_payment set method`  on the field `method` with the new modules namespace.

Example

```
update sales_flat_order_payment set method = 'inchoo_stripe' where method = 'radweb_stripe'
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed! Thank you so much!